# JQL query to get the amount of time an issue has been in queue

Tags: powershell, automation, jira, jira-rest-api, jql

I am using JQL in combination with [JiraPs](https://atlassianps.org/docs/JiraPS/).

My intention is to generate a report that displays the three users on my team, what tickets they've worked on this week, and how long those tickets have been in their queue without activity.

I know how to get the users and their assigned tickets. But I am having trouble figuring out the JQL syntax/logic to tell me how long their tickets have been sitting in their queue.

**Use Case:**
As a manager, I want to see how much time it took my team-members to follow up on an issue after it got assigned to them, so that I know how long it stayed in their queue, and use this information for training/assessment.

**Example:**
Jonny got assigned ticket "VV-ABC" on Monday but he didn't make a comment on it or reasssign it until Thursday, I want to be notified that issue "VV-ABC" spent 3 days in Jonnys queue before he assigned it back to the reporter.

What I got so far:

```
Get-JiraIssue -Query "updated > lastlogin() AND assignee = "Jonny" AND status != Done"
```

However, the above is not specific enough.

Can you help me structure my query so that the result displays how long a ticket spent in Jonnys queue?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.